# Xamarin Android Binding Library NoClassDefFoundError google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageLite

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, grpc

we're making an Android Binding Library for the [Polar SDK](https://github.com/polarofficial/polar-ble-sdk). Everything works well except for one method call (`setLocalTime()` - all other methods work) that fails with the following error:

```
Java.Lang.Throwable: Failed resolution of: Lprotocol/PftpRequest$PbPFtpSetLocalTimeParams; ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: protocol.PftpRequest$PbPFtpSetLocalTimeParams ---> Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageLite; ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn’t find class “com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite”
```

Does anyone know what could be the cause of this and how to fix it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This usually means that you are missing a dependency, either add it from NuGet or add a JAR/AAR and mark it as reference library.

Comment: Thank you @Cheesebaron I'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out we were missing dependencies. Not sure why they aren't packaged with the SDK's .aar file. I re-read the SDK's readme and added the right protobuf jar downloaded from the maaven site. The missing jars were marked as `EmbeddedReferenceJar` in the Xamarin project.
[image]